# Collecting values from a list of objects in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a method like this

```
static getList (long colorid) {
     ColorShades.findAll 'from ColorShades where color.id = :colorid', [colorid: colorid]
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
def shadeIdsForAColor = ColorShades.getList(colorid as long)
```

**Question**

The method returns an `ArrayList` of `ColorShade` objects and each object has a `shadeId` with it.

What can I do to put those ids as a list of integers into the `shadeIdsForAColor` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this do it?

```
def shadeIdsForAColor = ColorShades.getList(colorid as long).shadeId
```

Comment: hmm that does work.. So I can call properties on lists and they'll automatically be returned as lists? pretty sweet..

Comment: @Sharma Yeah, you could also use the long form of `ColorShades.getList(colorid as long)*.shadeId`

Comment: nice, that probably has less blackmagic at least till the time I get used to it.

Comment: @Sharma Yeah, i also prefer the `*.` form for the same reason :)